# Convert given UTC string and Timezone offset from JavaSscript to UTC format in SQL Server

Tags: javascript, utc, datetime-format, timezone-offset

I have been assigned a task where I have UTC string and timezone offset created in javascript code and they needs to be saved in sql server datetime column with UTC format.

- UTC string is created as `(new Date()).toUTCString();` 
  *Example: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 06:19:11 GMT* and
- Timezone is created as `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();` 
  *Example: -330*

Having no experience working with time zones, I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're looking for [*Date.prototype.toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring), which returns an ISO 8601 string in timezone UTC, e.g.

```js
document.write( new Date().toISOString() );
```

The [*toUTCString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring) method is implementation dependent, so not consistent across hosts. Also, the ECMAScript timezone offset has the opposite sense to ISO 8601 and those in common use, e.g. for a host set to UTC+5:00, *getTimezoneOffset* returns -300 (minutes).

If you need a pollyfill for *toISOString* to accommodate old hosts (e.g. IE 8), see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

Comment: Hi @RobG, thanks for your comment, Need some time to go through what you suggested, I'll mark it as answer once got assured of this at my level, else will get back with any query :)